# d3.js using d3.scale.sqrt()

Tags: d3.js

What does the `d3.scale.sqrt()` scale do? As per the documentation it is similar to `d3.scale.pow().exponent(.5)`, so the returned scale is equivalent to the `sqrt` function for numbers; for example:

```
sqrt(0.25) returns 0.5.
```

so when we apply a domain similar to this:

```
d3.scale.sqrt().domain([1, 100]).range([10, 39])
```

does it signify it takes the value between 1-100 and return the `sqrt` function which ranges between 10-39? Could anybody clarify and provide more details on how this scale works?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The way scales work in D3 is that they map input values (defined by `.domain()`) to output values (defined by `.range()`). So

```
 d3.scale.sqrt().domain([1, 100]).range([10, 39])
```

maps values from 1 to 100 to the 10 to 39 range. That is, 1 corresponds to 10 and 100 to 39. This has nothing to do with the transformation the scale applies, which only affects the distribution of values within the range. For the `sqrt` function, the growth is sub-linear, which means that more of the input values will fall into the latter part of the output range.